# C# Best way to compare fields of class

Tags: c#

I need to have possibility of comparison of Product, AdvancedProduct (and other classes that inherit from class Product)
    How it is better to realize hierarchical check of fields? For example, i want to check two AdvancedProduct classes, first i check fields the basic class Product then check additional fields of AdvancedProduct and return in some form (???) changes between  them (maybe class PChanges???). Whether there is a suitable template?
    How make all this, but to make rather flexibly for the subsequent use?

```
        public class Product
    {
        public string ID;
        public string Name;

        public Product(string id, string name)
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.Name = name;
        }


    }

    public class AdvancedProduct : Product
    {
        public string CurrentVersion;

        public AdvancedProduct(string id, string name, string version)
            : base(id, name) { }
    }

    public class PChanges
    {
        public bool NameChanged = false;
        public bool VersionChanged = false;

        public PChanges() { }

    }

    public class ProductComparer
    {
        PChanges changes = new PChanges();

        public ProductComparer() { }

        public PChanges Compare(AdvancedProduct p1, AdvancedProduct p2)
        {
            if (p1.Name != p2.Name)
                changes.NameChanged = true;
            if (p1.CurrentVersion != p2.CurrentVersion)
                changes.VersionChanged = true;

            return changes;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Uzzy's answer, looks like it can be extended to track the change. It is bad practice, yes, but for small app it should be enough. Example:

```
public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>{
    private PChanges change;
    public PChanges Changes{ get { return change; } }

    public bool Equals(Product p1, Product p2){
        PChanges newChange = new PChanges();
        bool equal = true;
        if(p1.Name != p2.Name){
            newChange.NameChange = true;
            equal = false;
        }
        this.change = newChange;
        return equal;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I misread the requirement of extendable field comparison. If that is the case, then Decorator pattern is the best for you. Assuming that every other Product class should be inherited from Product class.

```
public class ProductComparer{
    public virtual void TrackChange(Product p1, Product p2, ref PChange change){
        if(p1.Name != p2.Name){
            change.NameChange = true;
        }
        // other base validation
    }
}

public class AdvancedProductComparer : ProductComparer{
    public AdvancedProductComparer(ProductComparer baseComparer){
        this.baseComparer = baseComparer;
    }
    ProductComparer baseComparer;

    public override void TrackChange(Product p1, Product p2, ref PChange change){
        baseComparer.Compare(p1, p2, ref change);
        if( ((AdvancedProduct)p1).CurrentVersion != ((AdvancedProduct)p2).CurrentVersion){
            change.CurrentVersion = true;
        }
    }
}

public class ProductComparerService{
    public ProductComparerService(ProductComparer comparer){
        this.comparer = comparer;
    }

    ProductComparer comparer;
    private PChanges change;
    public PChanges Changes{ get { return change; } }

    public bool Equals(Product p1, Product p2){
        PChanges newChange = new PChanges();
        comparer.Compare(p1,p2, ref newChange);            

        this.change = newChange;
        return (newChange.CurrentVersion || newChange.NameChange);
    }
 }
```

The usage:

```
ProductComparer pCompare = new ProductComparer();
AdvancedProductComparer advCompare = new AdvancedProductComparer(pCompare);
ProductComparerService service = new ProductComparerService(advCompare);
if( service.Equals(p1,p2) ){
    PChange change = service.Change;
}
```

Comment: Ok, what if i want to check changes between AdvancedProduct class, there i have addiditional filed 'string CurrentVersion' so in this scenario i have to write new class AdvancedProductComparer?

Comment: If this answer works for you, can you mark it as answer? This will help the other user to search for similiar problem and get the right answer.

Comment: ProductComparerService class has some errors. 1 - Constructor ProductComparerService(ProductComparer comparer) must be ProductComparerService(AdvancedProductComparer comparer) and its field not ProductComparer comparer; but AdvancedProductComparer comparer;

Comment: I have missed the `AdvancedProductComparer : ProductComparer` inheritance for `AdvancedProductComparer` class and fixed it just a minute ago. ProductComparerService can accept `AdvancedProductComparer` now since it is inherited from `ProductComparer`

Comment: In AdvancedProductComparer public override void TrackChange(Product p1, Product p2, ref PChange change) --> public override void TrackChange(AdvancedProduct p1, AdvancedProduct p2, ref PChange change) but i cannot ovveride TrackChange(Product p1, Product p2, ref PChange change)

Comment: I forgot to cast the p1 and p2 in `AdvancedProductComparer`. Updated in my answer. After you have inherited `ProductComparer` in `AdvancedProductComparer`, you should able to override the TrackChange event.

Comment: [code] public override void TrackChange(Product p1, Product p2, ref PChange change){
        baseComparer.Compare(p1, p2, ref change);
        if( ((AdvancedProduct)p1).CurrentVersion != ((AdvancedProduct)p2).CurrentVersion){
            change.CurrentVersion = true; [code]  p1 is type of Product so when (AdvancedProduct)p1   p1.CurrentVersion will be always null

Comment: You can do custom validation in `AdvancedProductComparer`, that is like: `if(p1 is AdvancedProduct and p2 is AdvancedProduct)` then what, else then what. The validation implementation itself should be out of topic here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice library for .NET called Compare .NET Objects. It can be used to compare complex objects without writing comparison code. It is also quite customizable - you can tell it to exclude certain properties, include others, etc. It can compare both flat objects and object hierarchies. You can download it from CodePlex - http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Thanks, but my app is so small :) and this lib is SO big

Comment: Not a size. Get lib with tens of functions, when i need just one of it? But thanks for link it'svery usefull!

Answer (score 0):

It is better when ProductComparer would implement [IEqulaityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)

For more details see the example in given link.

Comment: No... I need that result of comparsion return CHANGES (look at PChanges)